# Is there a term for the following type of conduct: someone only responds to one part of your message instead of the whole message?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, terminology, idiom-requests

For those who know german: Die Person geht nur auf einen Teil der Nachricht ein

Here's an example to further elaborate:

**A (about something B said): She doesn't even sound rude. Maybe if it's said in a passive aggresive way, but I know her well enough to know that this is not her intention. Also remember the obscene stuff comes from her tourettes.**

**C: That's literally all you guys say whenever she says these weird things.**

C Only responded to the last sentence in this example and ignored the previous points and statements.

Comment: _overlook_, _ignore_, _cherrypick_, etc.

Comment: In your example, C could possibly be "skirting the issue(s)" raised by A in the previous points/statements but C might honestly think that all the points are related to B's tourettes and feel that s/he was responding to the entire message.

Comment: Thank you Papa Poule! That's what I was looking for! Also fair thought train, but you're missing context from the rest of the convo. It actually is skirting the issue for this one